# npm install -g creating folder called Password: everytime

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew

Here is the commands i used:

```
➜  code  npm ls
/Users/ravindrakumar/code
└── (empty)

➜  code  npm ls -g


➜  code  npm install coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
coffee-script@1.6.3 node_modules/coffee-script
➜  code  npm rm coffee-script
unbuild coffee-script@1.6.3
➜  code  npm install -g coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
/Users/ravindrakumar/code/Password:/usr/local/bin/coffee -> /Users/ravindrakumar/code/Password:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee
/Users/ravindrakumar/code/Password:/usr/local/bin/cake -> /Users/ravindrakumar/code/Password:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake
coffee-script@1.6.3 /Users/ravindrakumar/code/Password:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script
➜  code  npm -g ls
/Users/ravindrakumar/code/Password:/usr/local/lib
└── coffee-script@1.6.3

➜  code  ls Password:
usr
➜  code  ls Password:/usr
local
➜  code  ls Password:/usr/local
bin lib
➜  code  ls Password:/usr/local/bin
cake   coffee
➜  code  ls Password:/usr/local/lib
node_modules
➜  code  ls Password:/usr/local/lib/node_modules
coffee-script
➜  code  rm -rf Password:
➜  code  npm -g ls


➜  code
```

I tried uninstalling the node,npm completely using 
https://gist.github.com/nicerobot/2697848
But again after reinstalling i am facing same issue.

I have also created an issue in github, still there is no reply
https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3922

Comment: worth noting that ravindra has posted the fix to this in the github issue, which was to check that your npmrc prefix is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed by changes global npm configuration

➜  local git:(master) ✗ npm config ls -l | grep config
; cli configs
; globalconfig /usr/local/etc/npmrc
; builtin config undefined
globalconfig = "/usr/local/etc/npmrc"
userconfig = "/Users/ravindrakumar/.npmrc"

➜  local git:(master) ✗ cat /usr/local/etc/npmrc
prefix = Password:/usr/local

I editted npmrc now its working properly